Remove building name from Google Maps
There is a building name on Google Maps which I need to change. The actual school has moved and the PIN location is also updated but still "Olives School" still appears on Google Maps and points to this building which I cannot remove.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Olives+School,+Commercial+Area,+Judicial+Colony,+Rawalpindi,+Punjab,+Pakistan/@33.5946236,73.1331643,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x38dfeb6b049dcda5:0x144f37236656161!8m2!3d33.5946225!4d73.133808!16s%2Fg%2F12hlwdl16?entry=ttu
